# Sort Jtable row using radiobutton with sql in java

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, radio-button

how can i sort a jtable row using radiobutton?
for example i click the 'Name' radiobutton it will sort the Name Row in ascending.
im still new in java. please help me. thanks. :D

**whats the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular, [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Basically....

```
List <RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
```

Comment: what's the 1 and 0 for?

Comment: when i click 'price' radio button it sorts but in this order **1,11,12,13,2,21,200,3,32,300**. how can i fix it?

Comment: The values are Strings?